# Magento2.3 module upgrade not working

Tags: module, magento2.3, setup-upgrade

I just upgraded from Magento2.2.5 to 2.3.2 and now when I try to go to the site I get a bunch of errors written to the exceptions log file about modules versions being incorrect. For example

```
MSP_TwoFactorAuth data: current version - none, required version - 3.1.0
```

However when I look in the setup_module mysql table there is no row entry for the module MSP_TwoFactorAuth and when I run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

It doesn't create the needed database row entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this module moved to magento official repo (Member of MSP Security Suite) and now name is different. So You can remove old module.

New one:

> msp_twofactorauth

Please read:

https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_TwoFactorAuth   - there is a note here

and this is official repo now:

https://github.com/magento/magespecialist_TwoFactorAuth

Comment: so how do I get magento to not look for MSP_TwoFactorAuth I know to get the new named module i could probably do composer require magespecialist_TwoFactorAuth but that wont help with the original error i am getting?

Comment: Disable module, remove old directory MSP (do backup before) and run composer require msp/twofactorauth   I actually see on my database MSP_TwoFactorAuth
2.2.0 but its Magento 2.3.1. I ithink You have some conflict anyway, Can You paste exception log.